# 2 click events at the same time -> Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, multi-touch

I want to develop a game with Javascript.

Two Players can play at the same mobile device. I will need a method to check, when a player clicks. The Problem is, that they can click at the same time. Therefore I tried JQuery and native Javascript methods to handle these clicks at the same time. But nothing works.

Is there a chance to do something like that?

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: It would really be simultaneous touch events, not clicks.  What issue are you seeing that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: The players should click at the same moment and a function should count how often

Comment: Again, touch events, not click.  They aren't using a mouse.  And again, what issue are you seeing?  You are saying what it should do.  You are not saying what it is doing incorrectly.

Comment: If you are able to identify the players, you should apparently identify touch as well. All touch events will be invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, you're going to want to use touch events rather than clicks since you're developing for mobile. This should get you started:

```js
$(function() {
  var touchCount = 0;
  
  $('button').on({'touchstart':function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    touchCount++
    $('.count').text(touchCount);
  }});
});
```

```css
button {
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
  button:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }
  
span {
  display:block;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <button>Player 1</button>
  <button>Player 2</button>
</div>

<span class="count"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what i'm looking for.